# How to implement the Kolmogorov forward equation for a Poisson process?

Tags: poisson-process

How could I implement the Kolmogorov forward equation on the Poisson process?
I know that Kolmogorov forward equation is:
$$
P_{ij}'=\sum_{k \neq j}(λ_{k} P_{kj}P_{ik}(t)) - λ_{j} P_{ij}
$$

Comment: Please explain what "implement" means to you.

Comment: I had a test where it said “Write out Kolmogorov forward equation for the Poisson process”. I couldn’t find and answer or glue from course’s notes.